# How are the interviews for academic posts in Italy?

Tags: interview, italy

I have an interview scheduled for next monday in an Italian university. This will be my first interview outside of the Anglisaxon universities so I was wondering if anyone in this group have an idea on the interview process in Italian universities. How long does it take? How many people are there usually in the panel? How many questions do they ask? All information would be extremely helpful!!

Comment: How many questions are going to be asked is most likely based on the individual questioners and can't be answered generally.

Comment: What type of position are you interviewing for? Also specifying the field a bit may help.

Comment: I'd be happy to answer on the basis of my knowledge, but please specify the position first.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes, and voted to reopen: in Italy the interview process is relatively standard and a general answer can be given. It would be nice if people not familiar with the academic traditions of a certain country would restrain from voting to close so quickly.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano In the current state, it seems like it should still be closed because the OP has not specified the position. So it's still not answerable.

Comment: @ff524 Actually, knowing the position would help but it would be answerable even without the position. For instance, not only can you  know how many people there are, but also _who_ they are. Anyway, I'm currently heading for a trip and I won't be able to answer for the next 10 days.

Comment: I voted to reopen, so we can close it again with reason "unclear what you are asking". :) This question can be saved with a minimal edit, in my view, and "unclear what you are asking" conveys this meaning.